# Elastic Query to alert only when a certain logs comes more than a custom threshold

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

I have an echo alarm set like this:

```
{"query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
          {"regexp":{"messageDetail.uri": "\/v[1,2]\/ccpa\/.*"}},
          {"range":{"timestamp":{"gte":"now-60m/m"}}},
          {"range":{"responseCode":{"gte":500}}}
      ],
     "must_not": [
          {"regexp": {"message": ".*requestqueuedoesnotexist.*"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "size":0
}
```

This creates an alert whenever there is **one** response with status code `500` in the last 60 minutes .

I want to change it to alert only when **100** responses with status code `500` comes in the last 60 minutes instead of just one. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Hi @AmanKumarSinha, Could you provide more information one the implementation of your alarm mechanism ?

Have you looked into https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/alerting-getting-started.html ?

Are using some custom code + search query. look into aggregation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html. 

You could also explore is the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits. Still with a range on the timestamp.

Anyhow, I feel we might need more details on your side.

Comment: Thanks @Paulo for the links .I will take a look.
The current implementation is in kibana alarma. the query runs every 60 mins and if it find a log with message where response code is 500 ,it sends an alarm.

What i want is that it triggers alarm only when the cocunt of messages with response code is >100.

Comment: Hi @AmanKumarSinha, have you figured this out?